# Need a validation rule for two different account types

Tags: formula, validation-rule, account, operators

I have two account types, Provider and Partner.
My task is to forbid to create or change the record without entering a special code in a custom field. For Partner it should start from PRT, for Provider it should start with PRV.

I tried this way:

```
NOT( LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRT" ),
```

and

```
NOT( LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRV" )
```

When separate, both rules work. Please help me to set the proper formula for each type of account in one validation rule.

Thank you!
How it works
OR(
AND(
RecordType.Name = "Partner Account",
NOT( LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRT" )
),
AND(
RecordType.Name = "Provider Account",
NOT( LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRV" )
)
)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` for this:

```
1 = 
CASE(LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3), "PRT", 0, "PRV", 0, 1 )
```

Where the first parameter is the value to check against, then each pair of values are the value to check and the return value, and the final parameter is the default value.

`CASE`, for whatever reason, can't handle Boolean values directly, so we return 0 to allow the edit (1 = 0 is false), and 1 otherwise.

To combine the two rules directly, you would want to use NOT-OR:

```
NOT( 
  OR(
    LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRT" ),
    LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRV" )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

You are on the right track, just need to get to the finish line....

*NOTE: Keep in mind that when a Validation Rule (VR)'s logic evaluates to TRUE that is when the VR throws the error to stop the user.*

Your VRs work fine separately, but they work on either Record Type. So to get your first one, for example, to work with the correct Record Type, you need to add in the Record Type and us [`AND` logic](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_parent.htm):

```
AND(
  RecordType.DeveloperName = "Partner",
  NOT( LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRT" )
)
```

This will check: IF the Record Type is "Partner" AND the left three characters of the Partner Provider Code are NOT "PRT", then fire the rule and prevent the save.

You need to do similarly for the "Provider" Record Type.

---

So there are a couple of ways you could do this.

##### Option 1: One Validation Rule

Combine your original checks with the above-mentioned checks for Record Type with an [`OR`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_parent.htm) that will check for either one:

```
OR(
  AND(
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Partner",
    NOT( LEFT(Discounts__c, 3) = "PRT" )
  ),
  AND(
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Provider",
    NOT( LEFT(Discounts__c, 3) = "PRV" )
  )
)
```

##### Option 2: Two Validation Rules

As indicated, create a separate VR for each Record Type:

###### VR 1

```
AND(
  RecordType.DeveloperName = "Partner",
  NOT( LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRT" )
)
```

###### VR 2

```
AND(
  RecordType.DeveloperName = "Provider",
  NOT( LEFT(Partner_Provider_Code__c, 3) = "PRV" )
)
```

---

Which way is a matter of preference. You just need to think through things like...

- Whether you will add any more Record Types, thus requiring maintenance of multiple VRs or one potentially really long and possibly hard-to-read VR.
- Which would be easier for your admin(s) to recognize, understand and maintain.
- If you already have an in-house best practice for such a thing.

---

##### *EDIT*

*Changed `RecordType.Name` to `RecordType.DeveloperName`, which is what I meant to use from the beginning.*